# What could go wrong using gdal_calc to sum pixel values of a multiband raster?

Tags: python, raster, gdal, multi-band, gdal-calc

I have a raster, `input.tif`. I can open it using [rasterio](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and read 3 bands:

```
import rasterio
with rasterio.open('input.tif') as src:
    data1 = src.read(1)
    data2 = src.read(2)
    data3 = src.read(3)
```

Get the different values appearing in each band:

```
import numpy as np
print(np.unique(data1))
print(np.unique(data2))
print(np.unique(data3))
```

Outputs:

```
[181 201 217 222 230 237 255]
[120 156 186 219 245 250 255]
[145 156 176 179 191 196 199 255]
```

I want to add the values in each band to a new layer. I use [gdal_calc](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_calc.html) to achieve this:

```
python3 gdal_calc.py -A input.tif -B input.tif -C input.tif  --A_band=1  --B_band=2 --C_band=3 --outfile=result.tif --calc="A+B+C"
```

Read in the results:

```
with rasterio.open('result.tif') as src:
    data = src.read(1)
```

Print unique values:

```
print(np.unique(data))
```

Output:

```
[ 30 105 133 141 149 171 189 190 231 253]
```

I find this unexpected. If the values of the original bands were all more than a hundred (see above), how can the sum of bands have a value `30` for example?

What went wrong in the process above?

Comment: If you add values and fail to increase the bit depth you're likely to get integer overflow.

Comment: Oh ok. I did not find anything about bit depth at gdal_calc docs (https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_calc.html). Is there a simple way to increase bit depth for the output?

Comment: https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_calc.html: --type=<datatype>. Read also the notice `Despite the datatype set using --type, when doing intermediate aritmethic operations using operands of the same type, the operation result will honor the original datatype. This may lead into unexpected results in the final result.`  The program is simple and it is really mostly up to user to avoid things that should not be done, like sum 181+120+145 into byte that has max at 255. I can also see an example about on-the-fly conversion of source data with `--calc="(A.astype(numpy.float64)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integer overflow in Numpy addition is a [modulo](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d0/d86/tutorial_py_image_arithmetics.html) operation and does not saturate and clip the values at the maximum datatype value, or does not change the datatype to accommodate the overflow.

try:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.uint8(250)
b = np.uint8(10)
print(a + b) # prints 4
```

Change the datatype to `uint16`, `float32` or `float64`, depending on the use case.

Something along the lines of:

```
import rasterio
import numpy as np

with rasterio.open('input.tif') as src:
    data1 = src.read(1).astype(np.uint16) # float32 or float64 can also be used.
    data2 = src.read(2).astype(np.uint16)
    data3 = src.read(2).astype(np.uint16)

sum_data = data1 + data2 + data3
print(np.unique(sum_data)
```

for `gdal_calc.py` use `--calc="(A.astype(numpy.float64) + (B.astype(numpy.float64) + (C.astype(numpy.float64)"` (as per the comment from user30184).

Comment: The suggested gdal command fails with `0.. evaluation of calculation (A.astype(numpy.float64) + (B.astype(numpy.float64) + (C.astype(numpy.float64) failed
unexpected EOF while parsing (<string>, line 1)`, but otherwise great answer, thanks.